# Reduce API calls vs reducing the size of JSON by increasing number of calls?

Tags: performance, api

Which is better for performance? To reduce the number of API calls, but increase the data size being exchanged as a result... or increasing the number of API calls, so that the data size can be decreased?

Any other pointers?

Comment: There is no one correct answer. It depends on your use case, bottlenecks and what you wanna optimaize. Can you elaborate on what is the use case?

Comment: Generally speaking, I mean...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot will depend on the type or requirement. Like if you want a more real time updates then you cannot compromise on the frequency of the calls. Like wise if real time updates are not required then it will really help to keep the frequency of API calls to a minimum.

Generally speaking reducing the no. of API calls will be better. It will naturally help the server to handle more calls. You can always try and cache the data as much as possible in that way too you could reduce the volume of data being send. Like query cache at database, reverse proxy server, cache at html or use CDNs etc.

Comment: Oh I see, that is very interesting. Thank you for that insight. But it makes me think... if my web application has 5 pages, and each page has a number of different components being displayed... so it would be better to make a single API call with each page, but each API call will then require gathering all the various components of that page, creating one massive call. As opposed to making several independent API calls for each page, loading one component at a time.

Comment: There again you will need to consider re-useability. Like header, footer, side links etc. Those which can be reused can be cached. Hence when your application starts these components can cached with one call. The other components which changes per user can be then called and if possible cached as required.